# variaveis dentro de uma função - duvidas

Tags: php, mysql, funções, mqtt

Boa tarde,

quero montar um script que:

- subscreva um tópico em um broker mqtt
- o payload deste tópico é usado para uma consulta ao banco de dados.
- o retorno desta consulta será usado para publicar outro tópico.

para tal, encontrei uma classe mqtt que tem a função de subscrição, e apresenta o payload. usando o exemplo, expandi com a consulta ao banco de dados.

isoladamente, tudo funciona. mas colocando junto, apresenta erro.

o script:

```
.... definições ......
mqtt = new Bluerhinos\phpMQTT($server, $port, $client_id);
if(!$mqtt->connect(true, NULL, $username, $password)) {
  echo "Failed to connect to Mqtt: ";
  exit(1);
}    

$con = new mysqli($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_pass, $mysql_mydb );
if ($con -> connect_errno) {
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . $con -> connect_error;
   exit(2);
}
$con->set_charset('utf8mb4'); // always set the charset

$mqtt->debug = true;

$topics['rfid/card/ping'] = array('qos' => 0, 'function' => 'procMsg');
$mqtt->subscribe($topics, 0);
while($mqtt->proc()) {
}
$mqtt->close();

function procMsg($topic, $msg){
 echo 'Msg Recieved: ' . date('r') . "\n";
 echo "Topic: {$topic}\n";
 echo "Payload: {$msg}\n";
 echo $msg;
 echo "\n";
 // query con
 //$tagid = "39EAB06D";
 $query = "SELECT name, id  FROM rfidtags WHERE id = ?";
 $stmt = $con->prepare($query);
 $stmt->bind_param('s', $msg);
 $stmt->execute();
 $stmt->store_result();
 $stmt->bind_result($name, $id);
 if ($stmt->fetch()) {
    echo "$name $id\n";
    echo "1";
 } else {function procMsg
    echo "failed to fetch data\n";
    echo "2";
 }
 $con->close();
}
```

executando o código, saem os seguintes erros:

```
paulo@hp15pw:~/TOOLS/MQTT-PHP$ php subscribe-query-publish.php 
Mon, 19 Jul 2021 12:22:32 -0300: Received CMD: 3 (PUBLISH)
Mon, 19 Jul 2021 12:22:32 -0300: Fetching: 24 bytes
Msg Recieved: Mon, 19 Jul 2021 12:22:32 -0300
Topic: rfid/card/ping
Payload: 39EAB06D
39EAB06D
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: con in /home/paulo/TOOLS/MQTT- 
PHP/subscribe-query-publish.php on line 51
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on 
null in /home/paulo/TOOLS/MQTT-PHP/subscribe-query-publish.php:51
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: procMsg()
#1 /home/paulo/TOOLS/MQTT-PHP/phpMQTT.php(482): call_user_func()
#2 /home/paulo/TOOLS/MQTT-PHP/phpMQTT.php(547): Bluerhinos\phpMQTT- 
>message()
#3 /home/paulo/TOOLS/MQTT-PHP/subscribe-query-publish.php(36): 
Bluerhinos\phpMQTT->proc()
#4 {main}
thrown in /home/paulo/TOOLS/MQTT-PHP/subscribe-query-publish.php on line 51
```

entendi que em function procMsg as variaveis definidas não são reconhecidas.

while($mqtt->proc()) { ) é o loop que subscreve o tópico no broker mqtt.

dentro deste loop, uma vez que $msg ou seja o payload seja apresentado, verifica-lo no bando de dados.

como posso executar a consulta ao BD dentro desta função, retornando $name e $id para o principal?

Comment: Na verdade a pergunta seria: "Por que a variável `$con` está indefinida?

Comment: por que está sendo usada dentro de uma função - function procMsg($topic, $msg) - a pergunta é faze-lo dentro da função.

Comment: Passa ela como argumento

Comment: ok, como? esta é a dúvida.

Comment: Onde está sendo chamada a função `procMsg()`?

Comment: $topics['rfid/card/ping'] = array('qos' => 0, 'function' => 'procMsg');
$mqtt->subscribe($topics, 0);
while($mqtt->proc()) {}